# Extract "Date Modified" from all files in a directory

Tags: windows, powershell, datemodified

I have a large shared directory with a lot of folders with sub-folders etc...These folders and sub-folders contains files.

For all files in this directory, I need to create a text file that writes all files paths [,] data_modified.

Can someone help me to write that as a PowerShell script?

Thx

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer  -eq 0} | Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime | Out-File -FilePath "C:\files.txt"
```

Change the paths listed to your liking and it should work

Comment: This def. selects the correct objects. However, when the FullName is more than approx. 20 characters, the LastWriteTime is only partially written in the text file.

Comment: I solved it by adding -Width parameter on the Out-file.  Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer  -eq 0} | Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime | Out-File -FilePath "C:\files.txt" -Width 400

Comment: would it be possible to add the user who last has modified the file to the text file?